# How to make textarea to show text with HTML properties in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have added a textarea on my **home.html** page. The problem is if I am adding data line wise by pressing enter, now when i save it in the database and show it back on page, it comes in one line

**This is how I type:**

```
1. Line one
2. Line two
3. Line three
```

**This is how it is seen on the page:**

```
1. Line one 2. Line two 3. Line three
```

Below is my **HTML code:**

```
<ion-textarea rows="1" autosize #input (click)="focusInput(input)" (input)="change()" id="messageInputBox"  placeholder="Type Something To Send.." type="text" name="TAG" [(ngModel)]="TAG" style="z-index:9.99999; color:#818993;font-size:18px; ">
</ion-textarea>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use "innerHtml" like this : <div [innerHtml]="myData"></div>

Comment: but how will it make the text come in different lines ?  can you produce some code ?

Comment: you should use something like this : `<ul><li>Line one</li><li>Line two</li><li>Line three</li></ul>` if you use this string as innerHtml, the problem going to be solved! or you can use `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

Where you echo the contents of your TAG model in your HTML template, you should use a pipe like [nl2br-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nl2br-pipe) and use it like this:

`<div [innerHtml]="TAG | nl2br"></div>`

Be aware that you also should sanitize your HTML, before echoing it to your page, more on that [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/inserting-html-via-angular-2-use-of-domsanitizationservice-bypasssecuritytrusthtml/62562).

Comment: but when i am saving the text to db, it is not saving the new line tag, it is just saving the text, how do i make it save the new line tag then only i can use this

Comment: Don't save the <br> tags, just pipe the output through nl2br everytime you show it to the user.

Comment: Alright, so what i am understanding is, let the user type in the `ion-textarea` and i save as it is. Now, when i am showing the data, i pipe the output..thats it  ?  If yes, i'll try this and get back tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, 1 more guidance needed, how can i make the link clickable in the div, its not clickable at the moment , any advise on this ?

Comment: Don't know exactly what your output is, but I figure you can use something like the [angular-linky](https://github.com/dzonatan/angular-linky) pipe.